# Ordinal Data Set

Tags: python, machine-learning, ordinal

I am working with an Ordinal script, written in Python and I am looking for comprehensive Ordinal Datasets that I can run through the program. I have been searching the interwebs but wanted to reach out to you fine people to see if you all could recommend datasets I could play with or even good sites for free access to Ordinal Data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Kaggle is good source for your question , there is open kernel to inspire with
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets